# Qt: How to delete locally created multiple QIntValidator pointer object implemented on QlineEdit?

Tags: qt, pointers, memory-leaks, qt4, dynamic-memory-allocation

As per the Title, How to delete mulitple QIntValidator pointer Object created locally.I am stuck with an issue of memory leak.

I have a function as below:

```
void ABC::setTableDataItems(QStringList headerData)
{
    int row = headerData.size();

    int column = 0;

    if (_txtLineEdit != NULL) {
            delete _txtLineEdit;
            _txtLineEdit = 0;
    }


for (int i = 0; i < row ; i++)
{
    _txtLineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    _txtLineEdit->setMaxLength(_pktStruct[i].ItemDataLength);
    _txtLineEdit->setText(headerData.at(i));
    _pktStruct[i].currentLine = _txtLineEdit;

    QString regExp = "[01]{1,";
    regExp.append(QString("%1").arg(_pktStruct[i].ItemDataLength)).append("}");
    long maxDigit = getMaxValueForDigit( _pktStruct[i].ItemDataLength );

    QIntValidator* decValidator = new QIntValidator( 0, maxDigit, _txtLineEdit      );
    QRegExpValidator* binValidator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(regExp),_txtLineEdit);


    switch (_pktStruct[i].ItemDataType)
    {
    case DATA_TYPE_ASCII:
        break;

    case DATA_TYPE_HEX:
        break;

    case DATA_TYPE_NUM:
        _txtLineEdit->setValidator(decValidator);
        break;

    case DATA_TYPE_BINARY:
        _txtLineEdit->setValidator(binValidator);
        break;

    case DATA_TYPE_MAX:
        break;
    }

    ui->pcusim_cmd_task_tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, column, _txtLineEdit);
    connect(_txtLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(on_pcusim_cmd_task_tableWidget_linedit_cellChanged(QString)));
}

 }
```

In above function, I need to delete all multiple QIntValidator created dynamically (inside For Loop ) every time before the loop when the above function is called.

Don't know the way. Please give some suggestions / idea to proceed further ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do

```
  QValidator* pValidator = NULL;
  switch (_pktStruct[i].ItemDataType)
  {
  case DATA_TYPE_NUM:
    // create the proper int validator here        
    // ...
    pValidator = new QIntValidator(0, maxDigit, _txtLineEdit);
    break;

  case DATA_TYPE_BINARY:
    // create the proper regexp validator here
    // ...
    pValidator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(regExp),_txtLineEdit);        
    break;
  }

  _txtLineEdit->setValidator(pValidator);
```

That way you don't create validators that are not used.
Since you pass _txtLineEdit as parent on construction of validators, they will be deleted when their parent QLineEdit object is destroyed.
By the way, [setCellWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) takes ownership of the widget, so you don't need to `delete _txtLineEdit;` (assuming this is the one you passed to it, you should have created a list of them in this case)